# Edit code in Android Eclipse - how to best document/fold a closing }

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just realized that in Eclipse one cannot collapse code blocks like `{}`. The only thing one can collapse are `methods` entirely.

Now if a method does not fit on one screen anymore it is sometimes difficult to find the corresponding counterpart of a `closing }`.

I know the "Expand Selection To" in Eclipse but this is not optimal in cases one just wants to hide a block so the rest one is working on can only be seen.

For example in a code like this: ( EDIT: I formatted the sample code with Eclipse Format-command so it at least looks OK)

```
private void myMethod(String msg) {
    Boolean a = true;
    Integer b = 1;
    Integer justSomeCode = 1;

    if (a) {
        switch (b) {
        case 1: {
            try {
                justSomeCode += justSomeCode;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                justSomeCode += justSomeCode;
            }

        }
            break;

        case 2: {
            try {
                justSomeCode += justSomeCode;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                justSomeCode += justSomeCode;

            }

        }
            break;
        }

        justSomeCode += justSomeCode;
    }

    else {
        justSomeCode += justSomeCode;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I follow

```
private void method1() {

    if (condition) {
        switch (...) {  
        case a: {
            try {
                ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ...;
               }

                        } /* case a */
            break; 

        case b: {
            try {
                ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ...;
               }

                        } /* case b */
            break;
                }  /* switch */

    ....
    }  
} else {    /* if (condition1) */
        ...
}  /* else */

} /* method1 */
```

Having said that it is always preferable to have multiple methods rather than doing everything in same method.

Comment: ...this is exactly what I do in these cases, however using // instead of /* */ since its onyl one line...

Answer (score 1):

If you can no longer find the matching closing brace in some code, then it's **high** time to refactor your code. A first guess would be "extract method" to extract code blocks that form a logical unit.

Also, I don't know if it's just on this page, but your braces are all over the page in your sample code and aren't even propertly aligned. This makes finding the matching brace even harder, even in short code.

One way I change code for readability by removing huge code blocks is this:

Replace

```
if (someCommonlyTrueCondition) {
  // many lines of code
} else {
  // handling the uncommon case: probably logging followed by a return or throwing an exception
}
```

to this:

```
if (!someCommonlyTrueCondition) {
  // handling the uncommon case: probably logging followed by a return or throwing an exception
}
// many lines of code
```

It *doesn't* significantly reduce the lines of code, but it *does* reduce the indentation of the "main" code block *and* makes sure that the actual handling of the uncommon condition (possibly an error, maybe not) is close to the expression that *defines* what the actual condition is.

*Summary*: I don't know of a good way to "document" closing braces. The **best** approach in my opinion is to structure your code in a way that you don't need to document them, because their reason for existence is plainly visible in your code.

Comment: ...first you are certainly right regarding the sample I initially showed, that's why now I edited the sample so it looks OK. But where I can't follow, is when you say "structure the code....", esp. meaning refactoring. Here I try to avoid defining lokal methods that are just used only in one place. This might "look" good for some, but I find this jumping around confusing. Looking at xCode collapse possibility one can get the same "refactor" effect, but I find the code much easier to follow and maintain - just my personal opinion. (it seems however refactor is the only way in Eclipse/Android)

Comment: ...ps your suggestion regarding the "if then else" only works under certain preconditions where you may jump out in the if-case. There I totally agree with you and do the same...

Comment: That's true, that approach is not universally applicable. The universally applicable subset of this is "try to put the smaller code block first" (it doesn't *always* make sense, but tends to improve readability, when it does).

Comment: ...also this one I would qualify. I like to put the more important code first, if the smaller code is more than just a few lines... (where you would probably recommend to define another local private method for it... :)

Answer (score 0):

You're advised to extract the large blocks and make them private methods. It'll make the code look cleaner. 
I know this doesn't answer your question. Just a piece of advice and a good programming practice.